# What is the best way to fetch multi-level dictionary information in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a Dictionary of format

```
myDict: Dictionary <String, Dictionary>
```

For example,

```
“AUTOID-1” {
    “key1” : “val1_1”,
    “key2” : “val2_1:
},
“AUTOID-2” {
    “key1” : “val1_2”,
    “key2” : “val2_2:
},
“AUTOID-3” {
    “key1” : “val1_3”,
    “key2” : “val2_3:
}
```

For this entire dataset, I want to find out value of **AUTOID** corresponding to **highest** and **lowest** value of **key2**

Using

```
myKeyData = myDict.allKeys
```

I can get an array of all **AUTOID** and then I can use below for further processing:

```
for index in 0...myKeyData.count-1 {

    if let insideDict = myDict[myKeyData[index]] as? NSDictionary {
        // FURTHER PROCESSING  
    } 
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve the objective of finding **AUTOID** corresponding to **highest** and **lowest** value of **key2**

Answer (score 1):

I would use `map` to get an array of tuples containing keys (`"AUTOID-N"`) and values (`"valX_Y"`), and then get the `min` and `max` of that array according to a comparator that compares the values only.

```
let myDict = ["AUTOID-1": ["key1" : "val1_1", "key2" : "val2_1"],
              "AUTOID-2": ["key1" : "val1_2", "key2" : "val2_2"],
              "AUTOID-3": ["key1" : "val1_3", "key2" : "val2_3"]]

let key2Values = myDict.map{ key, value in (key: key, value: value["key2"]!) }

let minKey = key2Values.min(by: {$0.value < $1.value})?.key
let maxKey = key2Values.max(by: {$0.value < $1.value})?.key
print(minKey, maxKey)
```

Comment: so nice and functional

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`:

```
let myDict = ["AUTOID-1": ["key1" : "val1_1", "key2" : "val2_1"],
              "AUTOID-2": ["key1" : "val1_2", "key2" : "val2_2"],
              "AUTOID-3": ["key1" : "val1_3", "key2" : "val2_3"]]

let initalElement = (min: myDict.first!, max: myDict.first!)
let result = myDict.reduce(initalElement) { (aggregate, element) in
    guard let minValue = aggregate.min.value["key2"],
        let maxValue = aggregate.max.value["key2"],
        let currentValue = element.value["key2"] else {
            return aggregate
    }

    let newMin = currentValue < minValue ? element : aggregate.min
    let newMax = currentValue > maxValue ? element : aggregate.max
    return (min: newMin, max: newMax)
}

print(result.min)
print(result.max)
```

This assume `myDict` is non-empty. You basically choose the first element of `myDict` to start the `reduce` loop and compare it with the rest of the key-value pairs in `myDict`.

Comment: Why not just `map` the dict to an array of `key2` values, and min/max on that?

Comment: When I did that in the past, commenters were quick with their pitchforks "it's so inefficient!!!"

Comment: It's not, in this case